# firebase hosting:disable - how can i specify a resource name (website)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

When i need to disable firebase hosting i use this command:

```
firebase hosting:disable
```

But this only disables hosting for the default website. I couldn't figure out how to specify a certain resource-name, so that i can disable any of my additional websites.

Comment: did you try using `--site` option ?

Comment: it says: `unknown option --site`

Comment: what is your firebase-cli version ?

Comment: 7.0.1 (i have to type more words..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `firebase-tools` [v7.12.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.12.0), an option `--site` is now available allowing to bypass default site of a project :

```sh
firebase hosting:disable --site <site_name>
```